# Cannot find 'weak' in scope iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, closures

i am trying to avoid memory leak using clousures in swift , but swift is not recognising the [weak self] inside the closure.

```
  //  class :
    
    class LanguageClass {
        
        var languageClosure : (() -> ())?
        var name : String = ""
        
        init() {
            self.languageClosure = { [weak self]
                print("\(self.name) is the language")
            }
        }
        deinit {
            print("deinitialized")
        }
        
    }
    
   // consumption :

      var swiftLanguage : LanguageClass? = LanguageClass()
      swiftLanguage?.name = "Swift"
      swiftLanguage?.languageClosure?()
      swiftLanguage = nil
```

[image: closure and class]

Comment: `[weak self] in`, it's missing `in`.

Comment: This is not an answer -- though @Larme's comment is -- but sometimes it's because you're not in a block and therefore `weak` isn't possible.